# How do I force Entity Framework to use datetime instead of datetime2, during DateTime comparison?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am using Entity Framework for retrieving records and one of the filters is by `datetime`.

It generates a query like this:

```
([Extent1].[TxnDateTime] >= convert(datetime2, '2015-02-21 00:00:00.0000000', 121)) 
AND ([Extent1].[TxnDateTime] <= convert(datetime2, '2017-02-21 23:59:59.9999999', 121))
```

Is there a way I can make EF convert to `datetime` instead of `datetime2`? It seems much faster.

I want EF to generate this:

```
[Extent1].[TxnDateTime] >= convert(datetime, '21/02/2015')  
AND [Extent1].[TxnDateTime] <= convert(datetime, '21/02/2017')
```

With `datetime`:

> CPU time = 1234 ms,  elapsed time = 1250 ms.

With `datetime2`:

> CPU time = 1625 ms,  elapsed time = 1645 ms.

I understand that the .NET `DateTime` type maps to SQL Server `datetime2`. What are my options though?

The column is nullable `datetime` and I am comparing it to `DateTime?`

Comment: Can you expand on how your entities and schema are set up, the query you are running, and what Database/version you are using? When faced with SQL Server and a column type of DateTime in the database, with a DateTime .Net property type, I get the following:  convert(datetime2 '2016-07-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121) = [Extent1].[TxnDateTime]  There is no extra converts happening on the database column. The fact that yours is converting to string and then back to DateTime2 seems to imply that there is something weird between your column and property mapping.

Comment: You are right, the conversion was caused by a function I've used - `TruncateTime`. I managed to remove it, will update my question.

Comment: Running EF queries across entities and searching by ranges of DateTime values, the performance of the conversion to DateTime2 vs. DateTime is negligible to nothing at all. I ran a profiler across both sets of queries and the CPU cost, and Duration was effectively identical. (Sometimes the datetime2 was marginally more costly, sometimes the datetime run was more costly. (within 50ms of each other per run over 100k rows.)  I believe any performance hit you might have observed would have been due to the truncate function.

Comment: @StevePy, the difference between `CONVERT(datetime, '02/21/2015')` and `convert(datetime2, '2015-02-21 00:00:00.0000000', 121))` is half a second for me, in my database.

Comment: Just curious, but I wonder what would happen if you changed the "<=" comparison to a "<"? What you really want relative to the specified date(s) is >= startDate && < endDate.AddDays(1). Your original query looks more like <= endDate.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1). Since DateTime can only store to 997ms sensitivity, querying at > .997s may require extra computation. If you don't need the ms (or time for that matter) compare on date values with 0'd time. My test queries were on >= and < the date values with zero'd time.

Comment: @StevePy, I've just tried what you suggested. It generated `([Extent1].[TxnDateTime] >= convert(datetime2, '2017-07-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121)) AND ([Extent1].[TxnDateTime] < convert(datetime2, '2017-07-20 00:00:00.0000000', 121))`

Comment: Was there any change in performance?

Comment: Nope. No. Nah..

Comment: You should be looking to push things in the other direction - you should want *everything* (column definitions, etc) to be using `datetime2`. As the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql): "Use the **time**, **date**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard."

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, Interesting! When I create a simple database model with a table with a `DateTime` column, Entity Framework by default creates a column with a SQL DateTime type, not DateTime2. I used EntityFramework version 6.1.3

```
class Blog
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public DateTime IntroductionDate {get; set;}
}
```

Sql Server Management Studio reports that column `IntrdductionDate` has properties `(datetime, not null)`.

Anyway, A while ago I had the problem that I want every DateTime to be modeled as a `dateTime2` instead of a `datetime`. I guess you could use a similar method to force the column to use `datetime`

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<...> ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         // Configure that all used DateTime should be modeled datetime2:
         const string standardDateTimeType = "datetime2";
         modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
             .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType(standardDateTimeType);
         ...
    }
```

You can use this for all types that you want to model. For instance if you want to model that all decimals have the same Precision and Scale:

```
byte standardDecimalPrecision = 19;
byte standardDecimalScale = 8;
modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>()
    .Configure(p => p.HasPrecision(standardDecimalPrecision, standardDecimalScale));
```

Of course you could set the type of a column using `ColumnAttribute` data annotations, but that would force you to do this for every DateTime, with the possible errors that future classes would forget this.