# Enforce Entity Framework to use datetime than datetime2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, datetime

We have EF 6.1 and it converts all .NET datetime fields to datetime2(SQL) when executing LINQ to SQL query, which is failing in certain scenarios due to date comparison. Is there a way that we can enforce EF to use datetime instead of datetime2. FYI column in DB is datetime. I have seen answers of enforcing all datetime to use datetime2 but couldn't find anything which keep datetime to datetime. Any particular reason that EF is converting datetime to datetime2.

Just to make it more clear that in DB column is Datetime, C# properties is declared as datetime. When EF converts the LINQ to SQL query it sends particular datetime field as datetime2 than datetime. Column Edate and Pdate are datetime and I pass a filter condition with datetime value but when i see in profiler it gets converted to datetime2.

```
   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Project1].[ID] AS [ID]    
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID]        
    FROM  [DBO].[TableB] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [DBO].[TableA] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
    WHERE ([Extent2].[EDate] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Pdate] > @p__linq__2)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[DateP] DESC',N'@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7)',
@p__linq__1='2018-06-24 16:43:34.7830000',@p__linq__2='2018-06-24 16:43:34.7830000'
```

Thanks,
Punit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force Entity Framework to use datetime instead of datetime2, during DateTime comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177045/how-do-i-force-entity-framework-to-use-datetime-instead-of-datetime2-during-dat)

Comment: Datetime2 is a better data type than DateTime. In fact, [you shouldn't use DateTime again, ever.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)

Comment: @WoIIe Thanks As I said earlier that that particular article talks about enforce from datetime to datetime2, in my case we want to keep datetime to datetime and not let EF to use datetime2.

Comment: EF 6 maps DateTime to SQL Server datetime so your issue is probably different. BTW datetime2 is not better than datetime (as float(53) is not better than real).

Comment: @bubi `DateTime2` **is** better than `DateTime`, and here is why 1: It (can) use less storage. 2: `DateTime` has a bug implicitly converting string literals format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, that `DateTime2` doesn't have. 3. If can have a higher (or lower) precision. 4. It supports a larger date range (dates before 1753)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Nuget Package: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. After install, you can use HasColumnType("datetime") in your property.
:)