# Dynamic Linq passes incorrect DateTime format to DB

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime, dynamic-linq

I am using Entity Framework with Dynamic Linq library.
Have code like this

```
var myDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
var res = dbContext.MyEntities.Where("CreateDate < @0", myDate);
```

It worked well if I run same query on local collection, but on database it returns error:
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

I checked with DB Profiler and the reason is format that is passed to database. It converts date to '2021-01-01T00:00:00.0000000' instead of expected '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' and in result have query like

```
SELECT * FROM [MyEntity] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[CreateDate] < '2021-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'
```

that generates an error because SQL cannot parse this string. Tried to specify parameter as string but Dynamic Linq still converts it to this format and gives the same error in result. Are there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: I think this might [be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177045/how-do-i-force-entity-framework-to-use-datetime-instead-of-datetime2-during-dat) but I'm not sure so I won't flag.

Comment: It looks like EF is using [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) when your DB is expecting/only supports [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I assume your actual code uses more interesting search criteria? Because you should not be using dynamic linq in that example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks D M for idea. After some investigation I realize problem indeed caused by EF that uses **datetime2** instead of **datetime** for some reason when call is made using Dynamic Linq.
As solution I specified column type for my field in Entity class

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```

and it works now.